# How do I pipe an Eloquent HasManyThrough through another 1:1 relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

A simplified version of my schema looks like this:

**Events**

- event_id
- title

**Bookings**

- booking_id
- event_id

**Participants**

- participant_id
- booking_id

**Users**

- user_id
- name

**Users** are booked onto events via **participant** records, which belong to **booking** records, which are children of **event** records.

I am trying to write a method on the Event model to return all the users on the event, *as an Eloquent relationship*. I want it as Eloquent so I can chain where clauses etc., to further filter the resultset.

I have a participants() method on the Event model, that looks like this:

```
public function participants(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Participant::class,
        Booking::class,
        'event_id',
        'booking_id',
        'participant_id',
        'booking_id'
    );
}
```

This works, and returns a HasManyThrough that I can traverse, or work with further.

My problem is in trying to create a users() method, without starting a new query builder.
I want to chain something to the participants() method, to get the User attached to each participant, and return this collection as an Eloquent relationship.

I realise I can do the following, but I end up with a simple array of objects this way, rather than a queryable Eloquent relationship. Which means I've lost the ORM functionality I want.

```
public function users()
{
    $users = [];
    foreach($this->participants as $participant){
        $users[] = $participant->user;
    }
    return $users;
}
```

For reference, my Participant model looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Participant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function booking(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class, 'booking_id', 'booking_id');
    }

    public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'user_id' );
    }
}
```

How would I go about turning my **participants** collection into **users**? Is it possible to build Eloquent relationships (or collections) 'by hand'?

Comment: I think what your looking for is a belongs to many relationship? `$event = Event::with('bookings.users')` users relationship on bookings would be something like `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'participants')`

Comment: Show me your models?